# Angular CLI proxy one Docker container to another, bridge network, ECONNREFUSED

Tags: angular, docker, docker-network

I have an Angular application running in one VsCode dev container, and an ASP Core backend running in another VsCode dev container. Rather than deal with the mess that is CORS I would like to make my api calls to the Angular dev server and then proxy the calls to the ASP Core backend.

My Docker network configuration is this:

```
C:\Users\Martin>docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "90dcb78bded2417bba81f8ff71e232462eb23c4d72ecbfbfd8862beaafb7780e",
        "Created": "2021-12-27T10:10:23.2279842Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "44ae270de9b06f74f4c24daca75cf35ddb8beedb4d44e131881655b3669027b5": {
                "Name": "romantic_robinson",
                "EndpointID": "625a6feb4acabff027c164fce9fd3c1c0f3bfa35e8fabbfd8f1da668d3baf151",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e30c03da9479509aba2a2ab2b3ecd423e2679547fb72c86529428b317d503b73": {
                "Name": "stupefied_goldberg",
                "EndpointID": "20b1c9c3495b6b7941177a46fabf329d39b6b6058460839c7ea96bef06aa3bd7",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

My Angular proxy configuration is this:

```
{
   "/api": {
      "target": "http://172.17.0.2:5000",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "pathRewrite": {
         "^/api": ""
       }
   }
}
```

I would have thought this would result in the Angular proxy forwarding the request to the ASP Core container, instead it reports this

```
[HPM] Rewriting path from "/api/account/user-data" to "/account/user-data"
   [HPM] GET /api/account/user-data ~> http://172.17.0.1:5000
   [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /account/user-data from
   localhost:4200 to http://172.17.0.1:5000 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org
   /api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

I've tried using `localhost` the ASP Core docker bridge IP `172.17.0.2` and the Docker Host IP `172.17.0.1` and nothing works. I get `ECONNREFUSED` on everything.

I can't think of anything else to try.

Comment: I think you need change origin after "/api" :{}, "changeOrigin": true

Comment: I've tried that it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

In `Properties\launchSettings.json` for the ASP service I had to change

```
  // "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "applicationUrl": "https://0.0.0.0.:5001;http://0.0.0.0:5000",
```

This causes the listening service to listen on all available network interfaces in the Docker container instead of just `localhost`.

This also works

```
  "applicationUrl": "https://docker0:5001;http://docker0:5000",
```

I think this has caught me out with every single project I've created this year!